# working with keys with multiple values in hashtable dynamically in a loop

Tags: powershell

I'm currently working on a report, that will be later injested into excel sheet, using csv file content that will be generated at the end of script. I prepared a variable file that looks more-less like this:

```
app1name: "subid1","subid2"
app2name: "subid3","subid4"
```

I want to itterate through this list using foreach loop, that will generate this kind of output:

```
app1name;subid1;$var1;$var2
app1name;subid2;$var1;$var2
app2name;subid3;$var1;$var2
app2name;subid4;$var1;$var2
```

in order to export this to csv later. My goal is to run resource graph explorer kql against each of the azure subscription by refering them using subscription name (defined in file as subid), putting result in $var1 and $var2, generating abovementioned output. I prepared different versions of this variable list in both json and yaml formats and I converted it to hashtables, pscustomobjects and arrays, but couldn't get this working. Is it actually possible? I was thinking about preparing variable file in csv format like this:

```
appname;subid
app1name;subid1
app1name;subid2
app2name;subid3
app2name;subid4
```

Yet it'd be very convinient to have a variable file in formatting I mentioned in the beginning of the question, as it's more user-friendy format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to use the format you listed (below)...

```
app1name: "subid1","subid2"
app2name: "subid3","subid4"
```

You can use Get-Content on your text file, iterate each line, mung it up a bit with replace to get your app name and ids, build custom object and export to csv.

```
$file = 'C:\MyTestFile.txt'

# Test Function to get the variables from Azure
function AzureFunctionToGetVars {
    param($SubID)
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        'var1' = "$($subID)_value1"
        'var2' = "$($subID)_value2"
    }
}  

# Get the content of the file
Get-Content -Path $file | ForEach-Object {
    $appName = $_ -replace ':.*$','' # Get the application name
    $subApps = $($($_ -replace "^$($appName): ",'') -replace '"',"") -split ',' # Get the subIDs
    $subApps | ForEach-Object {
        # Create a custom object with the application name, subID, and the variables
        $results = AzureFunctionToGetVars -SubID $_ # Azure graph call
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            'Application' = $appName
            'SubID' = $_
            'Var1' = $results.var1 
            'Var2' = $results.var2
        }
    }
    #Export the results to a CSV file
} | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\MyCSVoutput.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Output:

```
"Application","SubID","Var1","Var2"
"app1name","subid1","subid1_value1","subid1_value2"
"app1name","subid2","subid2_value1","subid2_value2"
"app2name","subid3","subid3_value1","subid3_value2"
"app2name","subid4","subid4_value1","subid4_value2"
```

Comment: This is very elegant way of dealing with this, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to have your input in the form of literal PowerShell hashtable then you can import it using [`Import-PowerShellDataFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-powershelldatafile?view=powershell-7.4).

Given `test.ps1` (the `.ps1` extension is not mandatory, it could be just `.txt` or whatever):

```bash
@{
    app1name = 'subid1', 'subid2'
    app2name = 'subid3', 'subid4'
}
```

You can then import it and have a hashtable back. The only downside could be that hashtable are unordered so you would need to `Sort-Object` it in case you need it.

```bash
PS ..\pwsh> Import-PowerShellDataFile .\test.ps1 

Name                           Value
----                           -----
app2name                       {subid3, subid4}
app1name                       {subid1, subid2}
```